# How to use multiple arrays of items in one collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have one `UICollectionView` in my `UIView`. What I'm trying to do is when user press the button then other items(images array) appear on same `UICollectionView`.

Let's say I have two arrays of items:

```
   let items = [UIImage(named: "moses-vega-436582-unsplash"), 
   UIImage(named: "april6"), UIImage(named: "april4"), UIImage(named: 
   "april5")]
   let items2 = [UIImage(named: "test01"), UIImage(named: "test02")]
```

Now when user press the button I want to update my collectionView with images from items2. I'm using basic code for collections (it's easy for me to detect which labels for example to show. Because I have variable called "Testas" and if it's 0 then I know that it's default collectionView and else it's .... :

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
       numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        if Testas == 0 {
        cell.image.image = items[indexPath.item]
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            cell.label.text = "One"
        }
        if indexPath.item == 1 {
            cell.label.text = "Two"
        }
        if indexPath.item == 2 {
            cell.label.text = "Collection 3"
        }
        if indexPath.item == 3 {
            cell.label.text = "Rainy Days"
        }
        } else {
            cell.image.image = items2[indexPath.item]
            if indexPath.item == 0 {
                cell.label.text = "White"
            }
            if indexPath.item == 1 {
                cell.label.text = "Blue"
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

In conclusion, I'm asking what I need to write to pass items2 into collectionView when the user press the button and how to make this collectionView appear? (because it's not a function or something what I could call easily I guess). Keep in mind that I have a function where it counts items. So that's the biggest problem. I need a function to count my items2 when user press the button and then make images appear.
Thank you so much. Maybe it's not even possible to make what I want this way. I don't know.

Comment: Just put condition of checking `Testas == 0` in `numberOfItemsInSection` too, same you did in `cellForItemAt `. Like : `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if Testas == 0 {
            return items.count
        } else {
            return items2.count
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this easily by creating an enum, and then simply toggling it's value when the button is pressed followed by a collectionView.reloadData()

Here is your enum:

```
enum ItemType : Int {
    case items = 0,
         items2 = 1
}
```

Declare it like this:

```
var itemType : ItemType = .items
```

Your collectionView functions would look something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
   numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemType == .items ? items.count : items2.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    switch itemType {
    case .items:
        // code for items array
    default:
        // code for items2 array
    }

    return cell
}
```

Your button press:

```
@IBAction func onButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    itemType = .items2
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If you have more than 2 arrays you will need to update your collectionView functions to something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
   numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch itemType {
    case .items:
        return items.count
    case .items2:
        return items2.count
    case .items3:
        return items3.count
    default:
        return items4.count
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    switch itemType {
    case .items:
        // code for items array
    case .items2:
        // code for items2 array
    case .items3:
        // code for items3 array
    default:
        // code for items4 array
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank you, sir! Only one question. What if I have more than 2 arrays of items. What if I have items, items2, items3, items4? When I switch itemType I get error because index out of range. I made case .items: case.items:2 case.items:3 and default. Also, I can't understand what colon(:) means here return itemType == .items ? items.count : items2.count? Maybe it's a range?

Comment: return itemType == .items ? items.count : items2.count is a ternary if statement. It is just a cleaner way of writing an if statement such as:

    if itemType == .item {
        return items.count
    } else {
        return items2.count
    }